# CSS: nesting absolute div within an absolute div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="position:absolute; height:500px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">xxx</div>
</div>
```

If I position an absolute div with bottom:0 inside another absolute div, would the inner div always stick to the bottom of the parent div or would it stick to the bottom of the window (in certain browsers)? In practice, the inner div sticks to the bottom of the parent div but it doesn't feel like good practice and I worry it may be or become deprecated. Or is this perfectly fine?

Comment: Looks fine to me, you might set a max-height & overflow on child so it can show a scrollbar if it reaches past the top of the parent. Parent can also be in relative position to remain in the flux of the whole document.

Comment: This is the behaviour of nested absolute elements as according to the spec.  What you're referring to with the element sticking to the bottom of the window is an entirely different `position` value called `fixed`.  It is perfectly safe to use nested, absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Absolute positioning:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position ***relative to its closest positioned ancestor*** if any, or otherwise relative to the initial containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins.

Generally speaking, when you have a positioned element (basically anything but `static`), it creates a new positioning context for the child elements. (Okay, in reality this might not be quite this simple, and has some browser dependencies, especially when it comes to `fixed`.) In your example, the inner div would stick to the bottom of the outer div.

What comes to best practices, creating full-blown layouts with absolute positioning is usually not a good idea. For layouts, use things like floats and the `display` property. But other than that, there's nothing bad about using absolute positioning for things that e.g. are on top of other things and thus are really not part of the base layout. No fear of becoming deprecated either.

Comment: So an absolutely-positioned div would only stick to the window when it was not inside another div?

Comment: @5south To be specific, if the only parent is `body`, it will stick to `body`. Not the window. Use `fixed` to stick to the viewport, as indicated in the MDN page I linked.

Comment: Therefore, regardless of whether the parent div is absolute or relative, the child div positioned absolutely will always stick to the parent.

Comment: @5south Absolutely and relatively positioned parents are indeed _positioned_, so yes.

Comment: `position:fixed` for parent works this way too, only `static` will not be seen as positionning reference ;)